# After destroying user model, cannot add user model back in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I was working on Rails and getting a bit frustrated with my user model so I destroyed it (I'm also using devise which may be a source of error). In my defense I was tired, frustrated, and a bit on the tipsy side. I tried to add it back in with a simple `rails g scaffold user first:text last:text`, but I get the following error when trying to generate the model. How do I fix this all back up?

```
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)                  
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'                                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'                                                              
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'                                                         
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise.rb:285:in `get'                                                                 
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'                                                                  
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'                                                             
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'                                                              
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'                                                  
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'                                                          
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise.rb:319:in `new'                                                                 
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise.rb:319:in `add_mapping'                                                         
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:210:in `block in devise_for'                                                 
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:209:in `each'                                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:209:in `devise_for'                                                          
        from /home/action/workspace/surrigo/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'                                           
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `instance_exec'                                                       
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'                                                          
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in `draw'                                                                
        from /home/action/workspace/surrigo/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'                                                    
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'                                                 
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'                                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'                                                          
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'                                                             
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'                                                    
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'                                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'                                                             
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'                                                             
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'                                                  
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'                                          
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'                                                       
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'                                                                 
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'                                           
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'                                                 
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'               
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'                              
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'                          
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'                                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'                                   
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'                                                          
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'                                                    
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'                                                         
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'                                                      
        from /home/action/workspace/surrigo/config/environment.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'                                                          
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'                                                    
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Migrate pops the same error

Comment: Rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
uninitialized constant User                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in....

Comment: I get that error when I have a console or server still running. Make sure you shut them down before you migrate.

Comment: they have both been shut down.  :(

Comment: Are you using git for version control?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't completely remove references to your original user object when you "destroyed" it. What did you do? Did you remove it from your schema, did you delete the user.rb model file, did you remove references to User elsewhere?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Remove the line `devise_for :users` from *routes.rb* and try running `rails g scaffold user first:text last:text`. It should work fine.

The `devise_for` method expects `User` model to be present. Hence, it fails on loading the rails environment when you run the rails scaffold command

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have conflicts with naming conventions?

Try

```
rails g scaffold User first:text last:text
```

instead. 
You are generating a model for the class User (Classes are Capitalized CamelCase in Ruby)